# Is there any variation or end to Flappy Bird?

Tags: flappy-bird

Is there any variation or end to the game? At some point, at some score, does the difficulty increase, does the environment change, is there ever an end to it?

Comment: One variation I really like is http://flapmmo.com - exactly like the original, but with many, many players in there at once.

Comment: I discovered [Maverick Bird](http://terrycavanaghgames.com/maverickbird/) a few days ago. It's (presumably) endless, but right from the start it has unique and random obstacles.

Comment: Although I was asking about variations inside the game itself, I do appreciate your links, @KendallFrey.

Comment: And @RoryAlsop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No

The gameplay never changes.

Videos like this one are fake:

Comment: Then that's some damn good editing/coding (probably the latter).

Comment: Since the game was written in Java, it wouldn't be too hard to decompile it, modify it, and recompile it. It would be even easier if the game was written in some script parsed by an engine instead.

Comment: @Siddhartha it's a video editing channel. It was an ad-hoc work.

Answer (score 5):

As Strix says in [his comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156753/is-there-any-variation-or-end-to-flappy-bird#comment210151_156784), the probability of each pipe is considered independently. Take a coin toss as an example:

> Suppose that we have just tossed four heads in a row, so that if the
>   next coin toss were also to come up heads, it would complete a run of
>   five successive heads. Since the probability of a run of five
>   successive heads is only 1⁄32 (one in thirty-two), a person subject to
>   the gambler's fallacy might believe that this next flip was less
>   likely to be heads than to be tails. However, this is not correct, and
>   is a manifestation of the gambler's fallacy; the event of 5 heads in a
>   row and the event of "first 4 heads, then a tails" are equally likely,
>   each having probability 1⁄32. Given that the first four rolls turn up
>   heads, the probability that the next toss is a head is in fact, 1/2.

Source: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy)

The game only becomes increasingly difficult due to player fatigue etc.

Comment: You appear to be quoting from somewhere about the gambler's fallacy, care to add a link or reference from where you are quoting?

Answer (score 2):

No, the game does not increase game-wise.

It does, however, get more difficult.  This is not because the game itself is getting more difficult, but because the longer you play, the higher the probability that you will make a mistake.

This is called difficulty through duration.

Comment: You are no more likely to make a mistake after playing for 10 minutes than you are when you first start. The difference is that you have had more *opportunities* to make mistakes, which makes it more likely that you would have made a mistake to this point. The actual likelihood for mistakes at each set of pipes is static.

Comment: That's exactly what I said.  The game does not increase in canonical difficulty, it increases in user-error difficulty.  You just rephrased what I said.

Comment: You're not saying the same thing. The chance at each set of pipes that the user makes an error is the same (or if anything, decreases, since the user is probably improving in skill) at each set of pipes. The only thing that makes long runs more difficult is that you have to succeed in succession repeatedly.

Comment: The *cumulative* chance that the user has made *at least one error* increases the further along the track you are, but the *individual* chance to fail on *the next set of pipes* stays the same. That's the distinction.

Comment: That is what I am saying.  He did not ask if the singular pipes got more difficult.  He asked if the game itself got more difficult.

Comment: If you have a 90% chance of passing a set of pipes, then the chance that you pass 5 pipes is (.9)^5 or ~59%, but if you have *already* passed 5 pipes and need to pass one *more* pipe, the chance for that pipe is still 90%. The game *does not get more difficult*.

Comment: I am not saying that the individual pipes become more difficult. The cumulative difficulty is what matters.

Comment: I think the way you worded, "the longer you play, the higher the probability that you will make a mistake" implies that that player has a higher chance of making a mistake the longer he plays.  You might want to make a distinction between total gameplay and individual challenges.

Comment: But they do have a higher probability of making a mistake the longer they play.  That is exactly what I am saying.

Comment: The user has a higher probability of *having made* a mistake, but not a higher probability of *making a new* mistake.

Comment: Did I accidentally open up http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @StrixVaria, I disagree with you about not having a higher probability of making a new mistake. If the player were a static element, that would be true, but for a human, you have to consider fatigue. Either mental (attention span) or physical (cramped fingers) fatigue will increase the probability of failure over time.